# Django + SSL + mysql: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname'

Tags: mysql, django, ssl

I used Djano to build a simple restful API server. SSL has been introduced to the communication between the server and the remote database to enforce security. When the API server tried to write to the database, I got the following error:

```
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
  return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
  return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
  response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 434, in handle_exception
  self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 471, in dispatch
  response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/mobile/mpq_backup_response/mpq_backup_response/backup_response/views.py", line 39, in sms
  q.save()
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
  force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 821, in save_base
  with transaction.atomic(using=using, savepoint=False):
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 158, in __enter__
  if not connection.get_autocommit():
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 365, in get_autocommit
  self.ensure_connection()
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
  self.connect()
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
  self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 265, in get_new_connection
  conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
  return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 688, in __init__
  self.connect()
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 906, in connect
  self._request_authentication()
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1086, in _request_authentication
  self._sock = self.ctx.wrap_socket(self._sock, server_hostname=self.host)
File "/app/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
  _context=self)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname'
```

However, if I went into Djangon's shell interactive environment and wrote directly into the database, everything went smoothly. I don't why this problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to exist in OS X with python 2.7.10 and according to the link below, you will most likely run into this with CentOS 7 and Python ver 2.7.9 or above.

https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/477

Updating gevent to 1.2.1 seems to solve the problem.

You could run "pip install --upgrade gevent" on mac to fix this.